# Metamask Address not showing on remix

Tags: remix

After connecting my metamask wallet to remix via the injected provider the address of my wallet doesn't come up on remix

Answer (score 1):

1. Refresh remix with f5.
2. Click on MetaMask to see if it is expecting you to accept the connection.
3. Open MetaMask and to the left of your address check if it says "
   Not connected", if so, click on it and try to connect it manually from MetaMask. A little pop-up will appear, click on "Connect".
4. If anything, open remix again in another tab, check if it's connected, if not, follow the steps described above one more time.